# How to Total Hours and Minutes column in DAX |Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

[image]

I have a TravelTime Column and I want to Total the total travel time Column

Expected Measure in DAX (Total Sum in HH:MM): 10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write below code for getting sum of your time

```
Total Time = FORMAT(SUM(Time_data[Travel_time]),"HH:MM")
```

[image]

Comment: Currently, my data is Text type, when I change it, it give an error ()function sum cannot work with value type string, how to format this from text  to hh:mm@sam_shri

Comment: is it possible for you to change your time column from text to time data type?